# Makefile: changing variables based on target before building objects

Tags: c, makefile

I would like my Makefile to be able to compile with different flags/compiler depending on the target:

```
SRC := .
OBJ := .
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
BINARY := hello_world

all: $(BINARY)

$(BINARY):
  $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(SRC) -c $< -o $@

bm: $(OBJECTS)
  $(eval CC := aarch64-none-elf-gcc)
  $(eval CFLAGS += -DBAREMETAL)
  $(eval CFLAGS += -ffreestanding)

linux: $(OBJECTS)
  $(eval CC := aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc)
```

The issue here is that since each target depends on `$(OBJECTS)` (which I need to compile the objects) the lines that set the CC variable do not get set before evaluating. Thus, when I compile:

```bash
> make bm -n
cc hello_world.o -o hello_world
```

Instead of using the compiler and flags I specified. What's a recommended Makefile structure that would make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to assign make variables in recipes with `eval`. Use [target-specific variable values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) if you want to use them in the recipes. Use [conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Syntax) on `MAKECMDGOALS` (as you are apparently using GNU `make`) or custom make variables if you want to use them in lists of prerequisites.

Example:

```
SRC     := .
OBJ     := .
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c,$(OBJ)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
BINARY  := hello_world

.PHONY: all bm linux clean

all bm linux: $(BINARY)

bm: CC := aarch64-none-elf-gcc
bm: CFLAGS += -DBAREMETAL -ffreestanding

linux: CC := aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc

$(BINARY): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(SRC) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(BINARY)
```

But also consider that if you `make bm`, followed by `make linux`, `hello_world` will not be rebuilt because it is considered as up-to-date. An easy solution is to declare a phony `clean` target (as above) that deletes all object files and `hello_world`, and doing a `make clean` before building `hello_world` with a different compiler and/or compiler options.

An even cleaner way, as I explained in my answer to your other similar question, is to have 2 different executable files instead of just one, and also different object files. You could, for instance, use different `OBJ` values for your different settings.